# can't build IOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I encounter this error when i try to build for ios, i tried every solution i could find online

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from
    /Users/ahmedaly/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.13/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/ahmedaly/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.13/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal
    error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

Encountered error while building for device.
```

example of the things i tried:

```
pod deintegrate
rm podfile.lock
rm pubspec.lock
flutter clean
flutter run
```

and just about anything similar you could immagine
i also tried removing the file from the path indicated and removing the dependency from pubspec.yaml but it didn’t work

flutter doctor output :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in another question on Stack!

1. Backup `ios/Runner` folder.
2. Delete the `ios` folder.
3. Run `flutter create (your project name)`. in the previous folder where you have your project(`cd users/user/"projects_folder"`)
   (this will recreate your `ios` folder).
4. Paste your Runner backup in the `ios` folder (into the project).
5. Open `Runner.xcworkspace` (into `ios` folder) and there, check the Version, the Bundle ID, all the info.
6. (If do you Have Firebase, you have to copy and paste again the Google `Service-Info.Plist` into the `Runner` folder (Always through Xcode) (If do you do this manually, it doesn't work).

Finally, `flutter run` and should work!

If `flutter run` fails:

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. `flutter run`

Comment: i already tried this and it didn’t work for me